# Unable to Pan Audio using SoundManager2 Library

Tags: html, audio, soundmanager2

I'm currently working on an HTML5/WebGL based project that requires the use of stereo audio for locating objects.

In order to handle this I need to vary the Left/Right Stereo Pan based on the location and distance the audio source is from the user.

However, when trying to use the following code as suggested by the SoundManager2 Documentation (http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#sm-config) nothing happens, the audio remains balance between left/right

```
soundManager.setPan('soundObjectId', -100);
```

I've tried other forms, such as:

```
soundManager.createSound({
     url: '/path/to/some.mp3',
     autoPlay: false,
     pan: -75
});
```

I don't know how common SoundManager2 is as Googling around doesn't seem to show that many answers, I'm happy to try other libraries if they can be recommended for playing browser audio (must support IE11)

Comment: have this same issue have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing a very nasty workaround for this - I created two copies of my audio file in Audacity, one with the audio panned all the way left, and one panned all the way right. And then I 'mixed' these in SM2 by reducing/increasing the volume of the appropriate 'side' audio file. It works, but isn't a particularly elegant solution

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution for panning than this workaround? It's two years later and I'm running into the same issue :)